# Will I be able to train the neural network with negative values in feature vector?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, feature-extraction

I am working on handwritten character recognition . I have extracted certain features of a image to feed it to neural network. But , some of these values are negative. Can I feed these values to train the neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short but precise: **Yes**, you may feed the network negative input values.